# SailsJs :: Keep sessions with mocha

Tags: session, express, sails.js, mocha.js, passport.js

I need to keep my sessions alive between to mocha requests.

After login, I store in the user id in the express session object :

```
req.session.user = user.id ;
```

On a browser, the session is kept without any question needed (tested with Postman).

But, I need to make my REST API reachable for an external app, and I would like not to have to authenticate for each request on my API.

Is there a way for me to be able to keep the session between two requests in mocha or via the client app of the API ?

Thanks by advance.

English is not my mother langage, I may have not been as clear as I would have wanted. So I can provide any information you might need to help me.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Alberto, I figured out how to keep my sessions alive in Mocha with Supertest.
An agent keeps his sessions until its it destroyed, or the logout is requested.
What needs to be donne is use the same agent to login and for requesting the API.

What I did is :

```
var request = require('supertest'),
    should = require('chai').should();

describe('ImageController', function() {
  var agent = request.agent('http://localhost:1337') ;

  before(function(done){
      agent
        .post('/auth/local')
        .send({identifier: 'email', password: 'password'})
        .end(function(err, res) {
          if (err) return done(err);

          done();
        });
  })

  after(function(done){
      agent
        .get('/logout')
        .end(function(err, res) {
          if (err) return done(err);

          done();
        });
  })
  describe('POST /image', function(){
    it('should return 201 for image creation after login', function (done) {
      agent
        .post('/image')
        .send({name: 'test.png'})
        .end(function (err, res) {
          if (err) return done(err);

          res.status.should.be.equal(201);
          done();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks for the Welcome !
Can you explain me where I have put tags in the Title please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use supertest agent feature how can store cookies.

Has one example in supertest docs: https://github.com/tj/supertest#example

Sails.js example with super test example: https://github.com/albertosouza/sails-test-example

Test file example snipplet:

```
var request = require('supertest');
var assert = require('assert');
var authenticated;

describe('Example test', function() {
  // use efore all to create custom stub data
  before(function(done) {
    // use supertest.agent for store cookies ...
    // logged in agent

    // after authenticated requests 
    //login and save one agent with your session cookies. Ex:
    authenticated = request.agent(sails.hooks.http.app);
    authenticated.post('/auth/login')
    .send({
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password
    })
    .end(function(err) {
      done(err);
    });
  });

  describe('authenticated requests', function(){
    it ('should access one protected route', function(done){
      // use the authenticated agent to do authenticated requests
      authenticated.get('/protected')
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res) {
        if (err) return done(err);

        console.log('response:', res.text);

        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Github link is broken. Can you paste the relevant snippet in your answer please?

Comment: @Jamil done, see if help and i have one sails.js example with sails 0.10: https://github.com/albertosouza/sails-test-example